# Display URL in a Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, urls

I'm using the following code to display several custom fields on my posts in WordPress, but the URL field doesn't work as I want and I don't know how to solve it:

```
$destino_web = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'web', true);
$destino_telefono = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'telefono', true);
$destino_precio = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'precio', true);
$destino_horario = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'horario', true);

if( ! empty( $destino_web ) ) { echo '<p><strong>Web:</strong><a href="' . $web . '"><?php get_the_title(); ?></a></p>'; }
if( ! empty( $destino_telefono ) ) { echo '<p><strong>Telefono:</strong> ' . $destino_telefono . '</p>'; }
if( ! empty( $destino_precio ) ) { echo '<p><strong>Precio:</strong> ' . $destino_precio . '</p>'; }
if( ! empty( $destino_horario ) ) { echo '<p><strong>Horario:</strong> ' . $destino_horario . '</p>'; }
```

I would like to display the post title with my custom URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using get_the_title(), which needs to be echoed out. However, you have it inside the string. Also, you might want to use isset() rather than !empty().

Try this:

```
if( isset( $destino_web ) && $destino_web !== '') { echo sprintf('<p><strong>Web:</strong><a href="%s">%s</a></p>', $destino_web, get_the_title() ); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it prints the title but linking to the current post, even if the web field is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I had copied the $web var into my code, which you have not defined. I changed it to $destino_web to match the rest of your code. Also, I added a check to make sure $destino_web is not set to an empty string.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks!